# Converting date long value to current Timezone value

Tags: java, timezone

I have a date as long value, I want to display the Date format in words depends upon the country time zone. Please help me in converting this.

Comment: Date formate in words means for 23/01/2012 ---> 23 Jan 2012 like that ?

Comment: what type of string format you want?

Comment: @vignesh, check Joda http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `java.text.DateFormat` class. It provides several option how to output the current Data and Time.

For example the following code prints the current date and time in the long format option for the en_UK locale:
`DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK).format(new Date());`

Prints:
`23 January 2012 08:17:36 CET`

To display any date, just pass the long value to the constructor of the `Date` object.
`DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, Locale.UK).format(new Date(<your long value here>));`

Answer (score 0):

```
I have a date as long value
```

You need to understand date as long value is the absolute value (UTC)  of time in milli seconds since Epoch i.e. '1st Jan 1970 00:00:00'. This value has no timezone information embedded in it. Now if you want to display this time in your current local timezone then simply do this:

```
Date dt = new Date(1327303085000l);
System.out.printf("Date: %s%n", dt);
```

It prints:

```
Date: Mon Jan 23 02:18:05 EST 2012
```

Note the when it prints the date it automatically prints it with my current timezone.

However **if you want customized formattng** to display your date then you can take a look at the [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) class in Java.