# Convert Timestamps represent seconds since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970. to Date?

Tags: java, date, utc

I am using MovieLens data set, and trying to convert UTC Timestamps represented in seconds since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970 to Java date.

I could not find any useful resource for this. Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968249/converting-date-long-value-to-current-timezone-value

Comment: What does that timestamp mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) that takes a `long` as parameter.

```
Date yourDate = new Date(milliseconds)
```